# Aurora scheduler doesn't start

Tags: docker, mesos, apache-aurora

I'm trying to deploy Aurora on my Mesos Cluster but when it comes to run `aurora-scheduler`, it always fails showing a NullPointerException. Here is my setup:

- Docker container based on Ubuntu 14.04
- OpenJDK8
- Mesos 0.22.1
- Aurora 0.10.0
- 3 ZooKeeper instances
- 1 Mesos Master
- 4 Mesos Slaves

I'm pretty sure the ZooKeeper/Mesos setup is up and running since I can use the Marathon framework without any problems.

Here is my `scheduler.sh` that I try to run:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Cluster-specific environment variables
CLUSTER_NAME=test
ZK1=172.24.32.1:2181
ZK2=172.24.32.5:2181
ZK3=172.24.32.9:2181
ZK_QUORUM=$ZK1,$ZK2,$ZK3

AURORA_HOME=/usr/local/aurora-scheduler

# Flags controlling the JVM.
JAVA_OPTS=(
  -Xmx2g
  -Xms2g
  # GC tuning, etc.
)

# Flags controlling the scheduler.
AURORA_FLAGS=(
  -http_port=${PORT_WEBUI}
  -backup_dir=/data1/aurora_scheduler_backup
  -cluster_name=${CLUSTER_NAME}
  -mesos_master_address=zk://${ZK_QUORUM}/mesos
  -serverset_path=/aurora/scheduler
  -thermos_executor_path=/dev/null
  -zk_endpoints=${ZK_QUORUM}
)

# Environment variables controlling libmesos
export GLOG_v=1
export LIBPROCESS_PORT=${PORT_LIBPROCESS}

JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS[*]}" exec "$AURORA_HOME/bin/aurora-scheduler" "${AURORA_FLAGS[@]}"
```

I have followed the installation steps available on [the Aurora official documentation](http://aurora.apache.org/documentation/latest/deploying-aurora-scheduler/).

I uploaded the full output on [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/evLcBA3Z).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scheduler.sh appears to lack native log initialization flags. Aurora uses Mesos replicated log to store its state. You'd need to at least configure native_log_zk_group_path and native_log_file_path options to tell Aurora about replicated log. More here: https://github.com/apache/aurora/blob/master/docs/storage-config.md

Comment: You were right. I was missing the flags described in your link.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these flags as well as Aurora uses Mesos logs. Cf. @maxim 's answer which has now a 404 link in his answer.

```
-native_log_zk_group_path=/aurora/replicated-log
-native_log_file_path=/tmp/mylog
```